# struct arguments - array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Here's a simple code:

```
struct Car {
    var model: String
    var producer: String
    var year: Int
}

func AverageYear(years : [Int]) -> Int {
    var x : Int = 0
    for i in 0..<years.count {
        x += years[i]
    }
    return x / years.count
}

var list = [Car(model: "C400", producer: "Mercedes-benz", year: 2014),
            Car(model: "GLE450", producer: "Mercedes-benz", year: 2016)]

print(AverageYear([list[0].year, list[1].year]))
```

How can I replace `AverageYear([list[0].year, list[1].year])` - without enumerating all the elements? Something like `AverageYear([list.year])`

Comment: What do you mean by "without enumerating"? You're going to have to enumerate through the array one way or another to get an array of years, whether that's a `for` loop or a `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **map** to construct years array from the given array of cars like that:

```
var list = [Car(model: "C400", producer: "Mercedes-benz", year: 2014),
            Car(model: "GLE450", producer: "Mercedes-benz", year: 2016)]

let years = list.map { $0.year }
print(AverageYear(years))
```